# How to set the search path for data files to be used by pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

In the `tikzpicture` routine below I wish to use the data recorded in`invcum.dat` which I know resides in folder `C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\latex\pgfplots\plotdata`. All my attempts to set this path in either the preamble or as a parameter to the `\addplot` instruction, for example like so: 
`\addplot [blue] table[\table \search path={C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\latex\pgfplots\plotdata}]{invcum.dat};`
are failing.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 20 June 2019
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION: Setting the PATH to data files for use in pgfplots
%=======================
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

? how to set path to invcum.dat in the preamble ?

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=Inv. cum. normal,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot [blue] table{invcum.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you putting files needed for a compilation in the doc-folder?

Comment: Locating `invcum.dat` in the folder that holds my `.tex` file, still, `\addplot [blue] table{invcum.dat};` won't compile.

Comment: the miktex folder is not the right place to hold your tex file.

Comment: … actually the Error is `! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '$flags' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '$flags'..`. Not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Sorry I won't try to debug anything if you don't put the files in the correct folder. The doc-folder of miktex is not for your documents. Use the windows documents folder.

Comment: … and I don't know how to do that. Looking for your advise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think here is a big missunderstanding!

Your used directory `C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\latex` is **part of the tex distribution**. Do not use it for personal files! **Never!**

And regarding to your comment "… and I don't know how to do that. Looking for your advise!" see the following:

All your personal files you can store in a new directory under your system directory `C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\Documents`. Create there for example directory `mwe`:
`C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\Documents\mwe`. Now **move**  your file `invcum.dat` into this directory. Now copy your given code above into the same directory and name it `mwe.tex`.

Now you should be able to compile the `mwe.tex` without any changes, because the file `invcum.dat` is called in your tex file directly in line

```
\addplot [blue] table{invcum.dat};
```

(No additional directorys needed because the file is in the same directory your `mwe.tex` is.) Because you did not add an sample of that file `invcum.dat` to your question I can not test the compiling, do it please yourself.

If you need to have your data file and your tex file in different directorys, use a new directory based only on `C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\Documents`, for example `C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\Documents\test\data\2019`.

In that case you can try to use the line

```
\addplot [blue] table[\table \search path={C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\Documents\test\data\2019}]{invcum.dat};
```

Now it could be, because you have a space in your path of your file (the space between your firstname and familyname) you have to use `"C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\Documents\test\data\2019"` (please see the both `"` added!) for an working search path.  BTW: Better would be not to use spaces and special characters (like öäü) in your path and filenames ...):

```
\addplot [blue] table[\table \search path={"C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\Documents\test\data\2019"}]{invcum.dat};
```

Once again: because we do not have an example file `invcum.dat` I can not test your code and see perhaps upcomming other issues mentioned in error messages or warnings. So please do the testing on your computer and report the complete error messages (most important is the first error message; please see that a remark like "the compiling is failing" is not really helpfull. We need to know the exact reason for failing, so best you can do is adding the complete error messages (including line breaks!!) to your question(s)) in your question, and please add an example file `invcum.dat` ...

Please next time add all needed example files to your question! It makes it easier to help you ...

Comment: Your response is what I was looking for. I am also taking your advice regarding what information to include in MWEs on board.